# how to calculate regression between multiple variables simultaneously

Tags: regression

Assume a system composed of $n$ (unknown) linear functions $f_i(x)=a_ix+b_i$.

A sample of the system is a tuple ($c_1$,...,$c_n$) s.t. $c_i=f_i(x)+e_i(x)$ for a constant (unknown) $x$ and some error functions $e_i$.

Given a set of samples, I would like to estimate the relations between the functions (more precisely the affine transformations between them).
The errors can be assumed to be derived from normal distribution.
Naively one can deal with each 2 functions separately and use regression methods, but this will not use all the possible data and the results will not necessarily be consistent (i.e. composing the transformations obtained from $f_1$ to $f_2$ and from $f_2$ to $f_3$ will not yield the transformation obtained from $f_1$ to $f_3$). What I really want is to calculate all these regressions simultaneously.

Is there a good framework for this problem?

-edit- Consider the following example:

$n=2$

$f_1(x)=2x+1$

$f_2(x)=3x+2$

With the following samples:
$(1.05,1.96)$,
$(2.97,5.02)$,
$(5.01,8.03)$
for $x=0,1,2$ respectively.

By knowing the sample values only, it make sense to choose the transformation $f_2=1.5f_1+0.5$ or similar.

Comment: This is not a well defined problem : $\mathbf{c} =x\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}$ has infinitely many solutions (for $x$,$\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$)

Comment: Each tuple represents a single sample. In the problem we got a **set of samples**.

Comment: It doesn't matter, since all those samples depend on the same linear combination $\mathbf{a} x +\mathbf{b}$

Comment: Added an example to clarify the question.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks one might use to describe and solve this problem.  Anyone recommending one would likely want to know the intended application so that the solution will be appropriate for it.  Could you tell us what your actual problem is?

Comment: @yonayaha In your example $x$ is *not* a constant - it changes every sample. If this is the case you can in principle estimate all the unknown parameters (e.g. using OLS/MLE)

Comment: @J.Delaney Unless I'm misreading this question, it looks like $x$ is not estimable: you can rescale it by any nonzero number, $x\to \lambda x,$ and simply divide all slope estimates by $\lambda$ to compensate.

Comment: @whuber my actual problem consist of multiple clocks, each one with a slightly different rate. A sample is a recorded timestamp from each clock, and I would like to synchronize between them.

Comment: That's potentially a different question than the one you have asked.  Do you have only one sample of each clock?  (Unlikely, because then it's impossible to estimate the $a_i$ -- but your model doesn't accommodate repeated sampling.) And how are the time stamps obtained (independence of errors is the lurking concern)?

Comment: @whuber yes that's correct. I guess you can arbitrarily set one of the $a_i$'s to 1 (since the question is eventually about their ratios)

Comment: @whuber I have multiple samples. Each sample include timestamps of all clocks.